# Python Dynamic array List

Tags: python-3.x, list, dynamic-arrays

```
# Writing logic for extend function
def extend(self, *ArrObj):
    # Resize
    ArrObjSize = ArrObj.__len__()
    if self.n == self.size:
        # Resize
        self.__resize(self.size + ArrObjSize)
        
    # Copying content of ArrObj to self.A
    for i in range(self.n, self.n + ArrObjSize):
        for j in range(ArrObjSize):
            item = ArrObj.__getitem__(j)
            self.append(item)
    return self.__str__()
```

I am getting a nested list as output:

```
[69,100,Brenda,Kaley,[89,99,67,78,101]]
```

Expected output:

```
[69,100,Brenda,Kaley,89,99,67,78,101]
```

Comment: For the second for: cycle. Why do you use for i in range(self....) since it is never used? Just go with for item in ArrObj and use item as value from the list. You do not have to index it.

Comment: As it is right now you are actually amplifying the content of ArrObj. Let's say you have 5 new items. You go 5 times in for i cycle -> you append 5 items -> 25 new items insted of 5...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

By using the unpacking operator `*` before `ArrObj` in the parameter list:

```
def extend(self, *ArrObj):
```

all values passed in as arguments from that point on are assigned as a tuple of values to `ArrObj`, so when you pass a list as an argument to the method, the `ArrObj` becomes a tuple of the list you pass in rather than just the list you pass in, and the list in the tuple then gets appended to the output as a whole as you iterate over the tuple.

Your code would work by making `ArrObj` a regular argument instead:

```
def extend(self, ArrObj):
```

Also note that you can iterate over `ArrObj` with the following pattern instead without using an index:

```
for item in ArrObj:
    self.append(item)
```

Comment: Totally agree. Also the iteration via the list is one thing but iteration inside iteration which is 5x5 (new items in ArrObj) is Amplifying the content twice. Instead of 5 items right now he gest 25 items from for i in...

And index i is never used. So the iteration only breaks the logic here.